# Get distance in km in Postgis

Tags: sql, gis, postgis

I have 2 tables: City and River.

```
City: ID, city_name, the_geom (poin)
River: id, name, the_geom (multiline)
```

For each river I want to know the city farthest away and its distance in km.

For example...
I have the query

```
Select city1.city_name, st_distance(city1.the_geom, river1.the_geom)
from city city1, river river1
where 
river1.name = 'Albany' 
order by st_distance(city1.the_geom, river1.the_geom) desc
limit 1
```

In this case, I get the city farthest away from the Albany River.
Is this the best way to query?

I get this result:

```
City_name; distance
"Topeka";  13.2534798131185
```

But I don't know if the result is in km... If it isn't... How can I get the result in km??

Answer (score 1):

The units returned by [st_distance](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) are in spatial ref units - assuming you are using lat/lon (EPSG 4326) those units will be decimal degrees.

You have two choices - project to a suitable coordinate system in metres, or use the geography type.

Here is your query using geography:

```
SELECT city1.city_name, 

 st_distance(city1.the_geom::geography, river1.the_geom::geography) /1000 -- convert m to km

  FROM city city1, river river1
  WHERE
         river1.name = 'Albany' 
  ORDER by st_distance(city1.the_geom::geography, river1.the_geom::geography) desc 
  LIMIT 1
```

(Note: I am not sure of the value of casting to geography in the order by statement).

Comment: yes, the cast in the `order by` would be needed, else the ordering would be wrong as you move away from the equator (1 degree of longitude is not the same length, in meters, as one degree of latitude).

Comment: On a side note, the [`<->`](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html) operator would be usefull in the `order by` as it makes use of the spatial index